# After pressing the flat button several times, the noise coming from it stops in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, package

I am very beginner for flutter development. I am trying to create a launcherpad app. The buttons of launcher pad after pressing the flat button several times, the sound coming from it stops. Please help me to figure out.

Thank you

````
    return Expanded(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: FlatButton(
            height: 100.0,
            onPressed: (){
              final player = AudioCache();
              player.play('kick$soundNumber.mp3');
            },
            color: colour,

          ),
        )
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Row(
          children: [
            rowByRow(soundNumber: 1,colour: Colors.red),
            rowByRow(soundNumber: 1,colour: Colors.lightBlue),
            rowByRow(soundNumber: 1,colour: Colors.green),
          ],
        ),```
````

Comment: Piece of code, be more clear

Comment: `E/MediaPlayer( 9272): Attempt to perform seekTo in wrong state: mPlayer=0x5594543540, mCurrentState=0
E/MediaPlayer( 9272): error (-38, 0)
E/MediaPlayer( 9272): Error (-38,0)
E/MediaPlayer( 9272): Error (-38,0)`     **This is the error pop up**